# How does Lua find the right value for a specific local variable which has been assigned before?

Tags: lua

As the **global variables** are stored in the table named `_ENV`, **they could be found by the name as the keys of the table.**

**How does Lua find the right value for a specific local variable** which has been assigned before?

EDIT:

Here is the demo code:

```
do
    local a=1;
    local b=2;
    local c=3;
    
    sum = a+c;
end
```

How does Lua know the value of variable `a` is 1?

Answer (score 1):

Like all interpreted languages, lua runs on top of a "stack", which is quite literally what it sounds like. A big, tall memory structure which stores the entire memory of the lua script. (The term "stack overflow" comes from this stack running out of memory)

During lua compilation, lua looks for local variables, and allocates them a space on the stack:

```lua
local a = "abc" -- Item #1
local b = "abc" -- Item #2
local c = "abc" -- Item #3
```

When you run this script, lua's memory looks something like this:

```js
+-------+
| "abc" |
+-------+
| "abc" |
+-------+
| "abc" |
+-------+
```

This is also lexically scoped, when you enter a `do end` scope (or any scope), Lua creates a new area of the stack, and discards that area when the lexical scope is left.

```lua
local a = "abc"
do
    local b = "xyz"
end
```

Would look something like this:

```js
Before:    In "do":   After:
+-------+  +-------+  +-------+
| "abc" |  | "abc" |  | "abc" |
+-------+  +-------+  +-------+
           +-------+
           | "xyz" |
           +-------+
```

Interestingly, lua also has no "global variables". Every variable is on the stack, and is simply a table lookup.

The way this is performed is through upvalues; A lua scope can access locals in the scope above it. However, when you load in a brand new lua chunk (function) with `load`, it *has no upvalues*. To implement globals, all chunks have *one* upvalue, `_ENV`. All "global" variables are really just a index on this table.

Since _ENV is always at the very bottom of the stack, it's easy for Lua to look up globals. (It is slower, however)

```js
+------+
| _ENV |
+------+
+-------+
| "abc" |
+-------+
```

Final example:

```lua
local a = "abc" -- Item #1
b = "xyz" -- _G["b"] = "xyz"
c = b -- _G["c"] = _G["b"]
local z = "awesome" -- Item #2
```

To clarify: All operations in lua are on this stack. When you want to call a function- add two numbers, or even look up a table, all of these operations are performed on the lua stack. If you're interested in how this works, check out the lua C api.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. You see the "global" variables are found by the keys of the table named '_ENV '. How the Lua VM knows the value of the local variables (i.e  local `a`, `b` and `c` which are aforementioned by you.)

Answer (score 0):

Acording to [LUA Reference](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.2):

> Any variable name is assumed to be global unless explicitly declared as a local (see §3.3.7). Local variables are lexically scoped: local variables can be freely accessed by functions defined inside their scope (see §3.5).

so:

```lua
function printA()
  print(a)
end

a = 1
print(a) -- 1
local a = 2
print(a) -- 2
do
  print(a) -- 2
  local a = 3
  print(a) -- 3
end
print(a) -- 2
printA() -- 1
```

Comment: I see. As the global variables are stored in the table named _ENV, they could be found by the name as the keys of the table.How does Lua find the right value for a specific local variable which has been assigned before?

Answer (score 0):

Normaly local defined variables and functions makes sense inside a `do ... end` or `function(...) ... end`. For example my QLua on android dont print anything except `nil` when doing it without above rules...

```
Lua 5.2.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2013 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> local a=1
> local b=2
> print(a,b)
nil     nil
> do local a=1 local b=2 print(a,b) end
1       2
```

Comment: I see. As the global variables are stored in the table named _ENV, they could be found by the name as the keys of the table.How does Lua find the right value for a specific local variable which has been assigned before?

Comment: Dont know a way to do this. Local defined stuff without do end or in a function in the main thread means for me:  Feeding the garbagecollector - An exception could be the __index metamethod where you can store what is not visible what listing a table in normal way. - Example: ```setmetatable(_ENV,{__index={a=1,b=2,c=3}})``` - Then delete your global a b and c ```a=empty b=empty c=empty``` and try: ```print(a,b,c)```